# Build an AffineTransform object that match the transformation of 3 points

Tags: java, image-processing, transformation

I know the position (X and Y) of 3 points (p0, p1, p2) before and after an affine transformation. I want to build the AffineTransformation object that match this transformation. In other words, I want to find the affine transformation that will move the known points p0, p1, p2 to their known destination.

Here is what I've done so far:

```java
package image_transformation;

import java.awt.geom.AffineTransform;
import java.awt.image.AffineTransformOp;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;

import javax.imageio.ImageIO;

import math.Vector2d;

public class ImageTransformation {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

        // the position of the points before the transformation
        Vector2d[] src = new Vector2d[] {
                new Vector2d(486, 191),
                new Vector2d(456, 565),
                new Vector2d(149, 353)
        };

        // the position of the points after the transformation
        Vector2d[] dest = new Vector2d[] {
                new Vector2d(0, 0),
                new Vector2d(0, 600),
                new Vector2d(600, 600)
        };

        // the transformation that we are building
        AffineTransform at = new AffineTransform();

        // the translation to move the p0 to its destination
        Vector2d translationVec = dest[0].sub(src[0]);
        at.translate(translationVec.x, translationVec.y);

        // the rotation around p0 (it will not move) to align p0, p1 and p1's destination
        Vector2d vec0 = src[1].sub(src[0]);
        Vector2d vec1 = dest[1].sub(dest[0]);
        double angle = orientedAngle(vec0, vec1);
        at.rotate(angle, src[0].x, src[0].y);

        // the scaling to adjust the distance between p0 and p1
        // problem: it will induce a translation
        Vector2d origin = src[1].sub(src[0]);
        Vector2d target = origin.normalize().mult(dest[1].sub(dest[0]).length());
        Vector2d scale = new Vector2d(target.x / origin.x, target.y / origin.y);
        if (Double.isNaN(scale.x)) scale.x = 1D;
        if (Double.isNaN(scale.y)) scale.y = 1D;
        at.scale(scale.x, scale.y);

        // TODO compute the induced translation and apply its inverse to move p0 and p1 to their destination

        // TODO terminate the transformation to move p2 to its destination

        // apply the transformation to an image to check if it works
        BufferedImage inImg = ImageIO.read(new File("input.png"));
        BufferedImage outImg = new BufferedImage(inImg.getWidth(), inImg.getHeight(), BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB);
        new AffineTransformOp(at, AffineTransformOp.TYPE_BICUBIC).filter(inImg, outImg);
        File outFile = new File("output.png");
        outFile.createNewFile();
        ImageIO.write(outImg, "png", outFile);
    }

    private static double orientedAngle(Vector2d vec0, Vector2d vec1) {
        return Math.atan2(vec0.x * vec1.y - vec0.y * vec1.x, vec0.x * vec1.x + vec0.y * vec1.y);
    }

}
```

The Vector2d class do some basic math about vectors, each of its methods are self-explanatory by their name (sub[stract], mult[iply], length, normalize, etc...).

I have no idea how to terminate this algorithm. Also, if a method already exists that do all of this, I would be very pleased to use it.

Comment: This isn't solvable in the general case, I think.  What if all of your points are "0,0"?

Comment: All points are independant. Sorry, I forgot to mention that.

Comment: see if this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34852981/find-shifted-coordinate-in-skewed-square/34854277#34854277 can help

Comment: @gpasch The computation of `x, y, ..., s` there makes my eyes bleed, but it's a nice kind of blood ;-) Having a closed form (particularly, one that does not involve a manual matrix inversion) can be nice, so +1 for that one.

Comment: (To be clear: I just plugged the `calculateTransform` from the linked answer into my program, with minor adjustments, and the points are properly transformed to their destination, so the result is indeed equivalent)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is at least closely related to [Texture deforming, 4 points](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24344967/3182664), but I'd not say that it can be considered as a duplicate.

You did quite some math stuff there. But maybe that's not necessary. With the right approach, the problem itself is fairly trivial. Consider the meaning of an affine transformation in 2D: It transforms one space into another. The key point here is:

**The matrix columns are the results of applying the matrix to the unit vectors**

Now, when you have 3 points, you can compute vectors from them:

```
double dx1 = p1.getX() - p0.getX();
double dy1 = p1.getY() - p0.getY();

double dx2 = p2.getX() - p0.getX();
double dy2 = p2.getY() - p0.getY();
```

And then you can simply plug these values into the first columns of an `AffineTransform`. The last column of the `AffineTransform` contains the translation, which is given by `p0`. The result is an `AffineTransform` that transforms the points (0,0), (1,0) and (0,1) into the points `p0`, `p1`, and `p2`, respectively. When you **invert** this transform, it converts the points `p0`, `p1`, and `p2` into the points (0,0), (1,0) and (0,1) .

So all you have to do is

- create the transform that converts the source points into the unit vectors
- create the transform that converts the unit vectors into the destination points
- concatenate the two

The pseudocode (!) is really that simple

```
    AffineTransform unitToSrc = computeTransform(src[0], src[1], src[2]);
    AffineTransform unitToDst = computeTransform(dst[0], dst[1], dst[2]);
    AffineTransform at = new AffineTransform();
    at.concatenate(unitToDst);
    at.concatenate(unitToSrc.inverted());
```

The whole thing is implemented here, as an MCVE. The red points are the "source" points, and the green points are the "destination" points. You can drag them around with the mouse:

[image: AffineTransformFromPoints]

The blue circles indicate the results of applying the transform to the source points, and you can **see** that they end up at the desired destination position.

The actual computation is done with the `computeTransform` methods. Note that this is implemented based on `java.awt.geom.Point2D` class (and not the `Vector2d` class that you omitted), but this should be easy to change: The only thing that is used from the point- or vector class are the x/y coordinates. Beyond that, there is *no (custom) math involved at all* in the implementation. The only math is inverting the affine transform, but there's a built-in functionality for that.

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.RenderingHints;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import java.awt.event.MouseListener;
import java.awt.event.MouseMotionListener;
import java.awt.geom.AffineTransform;
import java.awt.geom.Ellipse2D;
import java.awt.geom.NoninvertibleTransformException;
import java.awt.geom.Point2D;
import java.util.Arrays;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;

public class AffineTransformFromPoints
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(() -> createAndShowGUI());
    }

    private static void createAndShowGUI()
    {
        JFrame f = new JFrame();
        f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        AffineTransformFromPointsPanel panel = 
            new AffineTransformFromPointsPanel();
        f.getContentPane().setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        f.getContentPane().add(panel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        f.setSize(1200,900);
        f.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        f.setVisible(true);
    }

}

class AffineTransformFromPointsPanel extends JPanel 
    implements MouseListener, MouseMotionListener
{
    private Point2D draggedPoint;

    // the position of the points before the transformation
    Point2D[] src = new Point2D[] {
        new Point2D.Double(486, 191),
        new Point2D.Double(456, 565),
        new Point2D.Double(149, 353)
    };

    // the position of the points after the transformation
    Point2D[] dst = new Point2D[] {
        new Point2D.Double(0, 0),
        new Point2D.Double(0, 600),
        new Point2D.Double(600, 600)
    };


    public AffineTransformFromPointsPanel()
    {
        addMouseListener(this);
        addMouseMotionListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    protected void paintComponent(Graphics gr)
    {
        super.paintComponent(gr);
        Graphics2D g = (Graphics2D)gr;
        g.setColor(Color.WHITE);
        g.fillRect(0, 0, getWidth(), getHeight());

        g.setRenderingHint(
            RenderingHints.KEY_ANTIALIASING, 
            RenderingHints.VALUE_ANTIALIAS_ON);

        g.setColor(Color.RED);
        for (Point2D v : src)
        {
            paint(g, v);
        }

        g.setColor(Color.GREEN);
        for (Point2D v : dst)
        {
            paint(g, v);
        }

        g.setColor(Color.BLUE);
        AffineTransform at = computeTransform(src, dst);
        for (Point2D v : src)
        {
            draw(g, v, at);
        }
    }

    private static AffineTransform computeTransform(
        Point2D src[], Point2D dst[])
    {
        AffineTransform unitToSrc = computeTransform(src[0], src[1], src[2]);
        AffineTransform unitToDst = computeTransform(dst[0], dst[1], dst[2]);
        AffineTransform srcToUnit = null;
        try
        {
            srcToUnit = unitToSrc.createInverse();
        }
        catch (NoninvertibleTransformException e)
        {
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
            return new AffineTransform();
        }
        AffineTransform at = new AffineTransform();
        at.concatenate(unitToDst);
        at.concatenate(srcToUnit);
        return at;
    }

    private static AffineTransform computeTransform(
        Point2D p0, Point2D p1, Point2D p2)
    {
        AffineTransform at = new AffineTransform();
        double dx1 = p1.getX() - p0.getX();
        double dy1 = p1.getY() - p0.getY();
        double dx2 = p2.getX() - p0.getX();
        double dy2 = p2.getY() - p0.getY();
        at.setTransform(dx1, dy1, dx2, dy2, p0.getX(), p0.getY());
        return at;
    }

    private static void paint(Graphics2D g, Point2D p)
    {
        double r = 6;
        g.fill(new Ellipse2D.Double(
            p.getX() - r, p.getY() - r, r + r, r + r));
    }

    private static void draw(Graphics2D g, Point2D v, AffineTransform at)
    {
        double r = 8;
        Point2D p = new Point2D.Double(v.getX(), v.getY());
        at.transform(p, p);
        g.draw(new Ellipse2D.Double(
            p.getX() - r, p.getY() - r, r + r, r + r));
    }

    @Override
    public void mouseDragged(MouseEvent e)
    {
        if (draggedPoint != null)
        {
            draggedPoint.setLocation(e.getPoint());
            repaint();
        }
    }


    @Override
    public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e)
    {
        draggedPoint = closest(e.getPoint(), Arrays.asList(src));
        if (draggedPoint == null)
        {
            draggedPoint = closest(e.getPoint(), Arrays.asList(dst));
        }
    }

    private static Point2D closest(
        Point2D p, Iterable<? extends Point2D> points)
    {
        final double threshold = 10;
        Point2D closestPoint = null;
        double minDistance = Double.MAX_VALUE;

        for (Point2D point : points)
        {
            double dd = point.distance(p);
            if (dd < threshold && dd < minDistance)
            {
                minDistance = dd;
                closestPoint = point;
            }
        }
        return closestPoint;
    }

    @Override
    public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e)
    {
        draggedPoint = null;
    }

    @Override
    public void mouseMoved(MouseEvent e)
    {
        // Nothing to do here
    }

    @Override
    public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e)
    {
        // Nothing to do here
    }

    @Override
    public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent e)
    {
        // Nothing to do here
    }

    @Override
    public void mouseExited(MouseEvent e)
    {
        // Nothing to do here
    }

}
```